# Process large dataset into numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

how can I process my large dataset of images (75,000 images) into an numpy array?
My attempt is to simply open the image and save it to the array, like this:

```
for i, image in enumerate(allTrainImages):
  if i % 1000 == 0:
    print("%d images processed!" % i)
  x_train[i] = np.asarray(Image.open(image).thumbnail(image_size))
  y_train[i] = np.asarray(train['class_label'][i])
```

The first 5000 images can be processed easily, but after that it takes forever to get to the next 1000 step...
Is there a faster method?

Comment: Without more details, it's hard to be specific. How are `x_train[]` and `y_train[]` defined? (`shape=(75000,1)` , `dtype=object`?) How big are the saved images? If I have to guess, I suspect the slow down is time spent reallocating memory for each new array. I think a List will be more efficient. Can you do that? Or is an array required?

Comment: 75000 image is a lot and should take a huge amount of memory if the image are quite big. Loading 5000 HD image (1080x720) takes roughly 13 GiB of RAM and up to 193 GiB of RAM for 75000 HD image! Do you really have such an amount of memory on the target machine? If Not you need to load the image by *small* chunks.